# Can I put the npm node_modules directory outside of my project

Tags: node.js, npm

Can I put the node_modules directory outside my project just the way maven does with its dependencies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sort of. The `node_modules` directory is not actually a feature of `npm` but a feature of `node.js`.

### How node.js uses `node_modules`.

When you require a module node.js will search for a `node_modules` directory from the current directory upwards. That means if it can't find one in the current directory (which may actually be a subdirectory of your project instead of your project directory) it will look for it in the parent directory then the parent's parent all the way to your root directory.

For example, you can have a project structure like this:

```
/node_modules   <-------------------- modules available to all projects    
/code
     /project_A
                /node_modules <------ modules available to project A
                /lib
                    /node_modules <-- modules available to the lib directory
     /project_B
               /node_modules  <------ modules available to project B
```

This way you can have some modules shared by multiple projects and some modules that are project specific and even some modules that are only available to some files in your project.

### How npm handles `node_modules`

Note however that `npm` has only one interpretation of `node_modules`. It only manages `node_modules` in your project directory. Specifically the directory that contains the `package.json` file.

So yes, you can do it but `npm` won't understand what you are doing and your `package.json` will contain incomplete dependencies. I wouldn't recommend doing this with projects involving multiple developers because it will look more like a misconfigured development environment - basically others will think this is a bug. However I personally have used such structures for personal projects where I don't care about my `package.json` file.

Comment: I would like to note that using node_modules in this non-standard way was not really considered strange in the early days of node.js before npm was developed and later adopted by the node project.

Comment: The major problem is that sometimes I want to search for something in my project ts files and I have thousands of such files because of the dependencies. Besides having multiple files inside my IDE workspace that I don't actually use it for nothing other than consulting them.

Comment: Here's an example of a personal project of mine with multi-level `node_modules` within the project. You will find multiple `package.json` files in this project that will install the correct `node_modules`: https://github.com/slebetman/movemachines - one in the project directory, one in mm16, one in m516/js516 etc

Comment: But that's just what I don't want. I want to place the dependencies in a directory outside the project just the way maven does with Java projects.

Comment: You can install modules globally but this is highly not recommended because of experience form other languages (yes, even Java but especially Windows dll) of dependency hell. The reason node was developed this way is to solve dependency hell. If you look inside your `node_modules` folder you will find other `node_modules` folder because even your dependencies have their own private dependencies. Disk space is cheap, programmer time debugging dependency issues is expensive

Comment: My problem is not disk space. My problem is that I add over 80,000 files inside my IDE workspace. And everytime I need to refresh the project because of git branch switching for example or I need to find a word inside a TS file, these operations have their times increasead a lot because of the number of files that the IDE has to deal with.

Comment: Your IDE should be configured to ignore node_modules. Or if it can't (like VS code) you should ignore node_modules - your IDE doesn't force you to open files

Comment: Of course I ignore what I don't want. What I do want is the IDE to also ignore these files so as to these operations take less time to complete. By any chance, do you use eclipse IDE and know how to make it ignore these files?

Comment: I don't use Eclipse. What operations are taking time?

Comment: Refresh contents of a project and locate a word in a TS, CSS file.

Answer (score 2):

As mention in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491709/access-node-modules-from-another-folder) question Don't do it. Let NPM work the way it's designed to. However, to save space, you can delete the node_modules folder on projects that are currently dormant, and recreate it with a single shot of npm install when you switch back to them.

It is an issue if the plugin declares to install the modules in a configurable directory. Therefore I suggest to fix the documentation, it gives false hopes.
Please see [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders), as this is the default behaviour of npm. Not a frontend-maven-plugin issue.

Comment: The problem is not disk space, but a whole bunch of files that I don't actually use for nothing other than consulting them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but you should try to avoid doing so.

`npm install` will always install the modules within node_modules folder in your parent working directory.

Whenever you install a module using `npm install -g module_name`, it installs modules globally outside your project directory which can be also used in other projects, normally some dev dependencies are installed globally which helps you in development purpose.

An example would be 
`npm install -g @angular/cli` , doing this once will enable you to use `ng` commands to build ,test other angular projects as well.

Other than this,it would be ideal if all the node_modules which are required for your project would stay in the working directory of your project.

Installing anything globally outside your project is considered bad practice  as different projects may depend on different versions of the same node_module.Installing node_modules locally within the project directory allows different projects to have different versions of same node_module.

Comment: No way to do it the maven way?

Comment: `Installing anything globally outside your project is considered bad practice as different projects may depend on different versions of the same node_module.Installing node_modules locally within the project directory allows different projects to have different versions of same node_module.` Can you explain it a little bit further? How can `different projects have different versions of SAME node_module` if the node_module is local to each project?

Comment: Lets say for example you have a node_module called `rxjs` with version `5.0.0` which you have installed globally, your local  `Project A` use few methods from that module to work , now after few days you clone a new `Project B` which uses new methods from rxjs latest version( `6.0.0` ) which doesn't exist in `5.0.0`.however since the globally installed version stands at 5.0.0, your new `Project B` will have breaking code since it will search for new methods which doesn't exist in `5.0.0` version

Comment: By `different projects have different versions of SAME node_module`, I meant when you keep your node_module local within project directory, as explained in the above comment `Project A` will have `rxjs` version `5.0.0` as it will be installed w.r.t its `package.json` and `Project B` will have version `6.0.0`  as it will be installed referring `Project B` `package.json`.So both project have its own node_modules folder with  different version of same (`rxjs`)  node_module  thereby not breaking the code in both projects.

Comment: I really don't understand why npm does not manage dependencies as Maven does. Maven does it globally and the project does not break because you explicitly declare the version you want for each one of your dependencies the same way you do with npm. But even if you have to work this way, at least npm shouldn't force the node_modules directory to be inside your working directory, maybe place in another directory and create node_modules inside a project folder and this project folder inside this other directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can, **only** for learning purposes.

'ng new xyz' does 2 things:

1. Create a workspace named xyz
2. Create a default app inside this new workspace.

So when you use ng new abc, you might be thinking that abc is a project / app - it's not - it's a workspace. Naturally, every new workspace will have its own libraries!

The commands

1. `ng new my-angular-workspace --create-application=false`
2. `cd my-angular-workspace`
3. `ng generate application myapp1`
4. `ng g app myapp2`

You will find that your workspace has a folder called projects, and projects has 2 folders myapp1 and myapp2. And these apps will have a common:

- node_modules folder
- config json for TypeScript, Angular and Packaging

Now to run myapp1, use `ng serve myapp1 -o`