# How to run `ng serve` to use global packages?

Tags: angular, npm

If I run `npm` to download and install packages globally for my project everything is fine:

```
C:\app>npm install -g

up to date, audited 3 packages in 587ms

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

But when I run `ng serve --port 34000` I got the following error:

```
C:\app>ng serve --port 34000
Node packages may not be installed. Try installing with 'npm install'.
Error: Could not find the '@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server' builder's node package.
```

Yes, using `npm install` command do resolve the problem, but unfortunately running this command creates the additional about 1G `node_modules` folder for each project.

Is it possible to run the `ng serve` and specify to use packages from *global* location?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think to clarify is that node_modules is created due to it's a node project, not because of being an angular. By the way, doing that is not a good practice, you should use NPM work the way it's designed to.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62050715/can-i-put-the-npm-node-modules-directory-outside-of-my-project) someone was asking the same, where you can inform about how node_modules works and why it's not possible, instead of maven, where it's a normal practice.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I will check any related solutions from this post. According the post, you are referencing, the `node_modules` directory might be located in parent directories of projects, but I want to found a way how to configure the [`ng serve`](https://angular.io/cli/serve#ng-serve) command to use packages from these `node_modules` folders.