# Multiple node_modules directories

Tags: node.js, npm, ckeditor, node-modules

I am using laravel and after `npm install` it generates a node_modules folder.

Now I need to add a custom build of CKeditor (or any other software, doesn't matter). So, in `resources/js/` I clone the CKEditor which has its own package.json. In order to build the editor I need to run `npm install` from inside this subfolder. It then creates a new node_modules folder inside /resources/js/ckeditor.

Now I have 2 node_modules folder with overlapping dependancies. Even worse is that when I deploy the code I have to remember to run `npm install` inside my subfolder.

Is there common use-case that addresses issues like this or is this the normal workflow?

Comment: Yes this is normal workflow, dependencies may overlap and are even expected to overlap since used versions may differ between projects. This answer explains it better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36492676/10353987

Comment: @etarhan thanks. But the answer you pasted talks for sharing node_modules between different projects. In my case, I have one project and 2 node_modules. Now, if I need to build a custom tool for use inside my project, I may need to add yet another, third node_modules folder (3 package.json files). Deployment would become super annoying, having to remember all the places one needs to run `npm install` in.