# How to use node_modules present in a different directory for a react project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I want to have a separate directory such as /lib/node_modules from where my create-react-app should refer to. Not instead of parent react directory...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Nishant Consider [Taking a tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also see [Access node_modules from another folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491709/access-node-modules-from-another-folder)

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293049/specify-path-to-node-modules-in-package-json

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specify path to node\_modules in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293049/specify-path-to-node-modules-in-package-json)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using windows symbolic links.
refer to this website - [creating symbolic links](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/).
I used (J) as it stands for directory junction.
Code to run on windows terminal :-

> mklink /J "path\name of the creating folder" "path\name of the original folder"

for more info - [watch](https://youtu.be/2x6FXDAJOA0)